# Firebase Function call returns "NOT_FOUND" exception. (Android, koltin)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use Firebase Functions in my koltin Android app to send a message from a client device to another.

## Firebase Function within index.js

```js
 exports.callUser = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
   console.log('Call request received.');
   // Message text passed from the client.
   const registrationToken = data.registrationToken;
   functions.logger.log('Calling', registrationToken);
   var message = {
     data: {
       doctor: 'foo',
       patient: 'bar',
       room: 'foobar'
     },
     token: registrationToken
   };
   return admin.messaging().send(message)
       .then((response) => {
           console.log('Successfully sent incoming call message:', response);
           return "Sent";
       })
       .catch((error) => {
           console.log('Error sending message:', error);
           throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
       });
 });
```

## Firebase function client call

```
private fun makeCall(registrationToken: String): Task<String> {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    val data = hashMapOf(
        "registrationToken" to registrationToken
    )
    Log.d(TAG, "callUser data input: $data")
    return Firebase.functions
        .getHttpsCallable("callUser")
        .call(data)
        .continueWith { task ->
            val result = task.result?.data as String
            result
        }
}
```

## Exception Handling from function

```
makeCall(registrationToken)
.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
        val e = task.exception
        if (e is FirebaseFunctionsException) {
            val code = e.code
            val details = e.details
            Log.w(TAG, "$code")
        }
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        Log.w(TAG, "addMessage:onFailure", e)
        showSnackbar("An error occurred.")
        return@OnCompleteListener
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    val result = task.result
    Log.d(TAG,"MakeCall result: $result")
    val intent = Intent(activity, VideoActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
})
```

I have been able to write simple https.onRequest() functions which work as expected but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with this callback function.

## Logs

```
W/HomeFragment: NOT_FOUND
W/HomeFragment: addMessage:onFailure
com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: NOT_FOUND
    at com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions$2.onResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase- 
    functions@@19.0.2:281)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I am using the Firebase emulator to test, there are no logs from that as the function never gets called successfully.

Comment: I have run the firebase function in a node shell and it works. It is just the calling of it from the client app which does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because I was using the Firebase Emulator. Before accessing 'Firebase.functions' you must include 'FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().useFunctionsEmulator("http://10.0.2.2:5001")' if you wish to use the emulator.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions#callable_functions